# How do I skip certain lines of code to move back up in a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Note: I'm using `pyinputplus` module...

Go to the `elif sub_inp == 'Go Back':` line, I need to skip the rest of the code and come back to the start of the main while loop if user chooses Go Back:

```
choice_loop = 'yes'
while choice_loop == 'yes':

    # Taking main_inp (this is choice between calculator or unit converter)

    # Nested While loop for making repeated use of a single operation possible
    sub_loop = 'yes'
    while sub_loop == 'yes':

                # here sub_inp is taken (this is choice between some different types of calculators)
                # rest of my text based calculator here

                elif sub_inp == 'Go Back':
                    # HERE IS THE PROBLEM/ISSURE, What should I do here to skip the code below to directly go back to taking main_inp above ??
                
                # Internal While loop repeater
                internal_loop = inputYesNo(f'\nDo you want to conduct {sub_inp} again ? [Yes/No]:  ')
                if internal_loop == 'yes':
                    print()
                    continue
                else:
                    break

# After many lines of text based unit converter (its same as the calculator section above but just with diff operations)
# at the end this also has a internal_loop and after this whole loop ends sub_loop runs

        # Sub While loop repeater
        sub_loop = inputYesNo(f'\nDo you want to conduct an operation in the {main_inp} Category? [Yes/No]: ')
        if sub_loop == 'yes':
            print()
            continue
        else:
            break

    # Main While loop repeater:
    choice_loop = inputYesNo('\nDo you want to access another Category ? [Yes/No]: ')
    if choice_loop == 'yes':
        continue
    else:
        break # Code ends here

# I need a way to skip internal and sub loop to directly go back to main loop if user chooses to go back (if they choose a option by mistake)
```

I've plans to learn PySide6 and make this in GUI form just to learn GUIs but currently help me resolve this please!

I tried thinking of something but no luck: `quit()`, `exit()`, `break`, `continue`. I'm not using them correctly to achieve my end goal

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to factor your inner while loop scope into a function that you can return early from. Otherwise you need to add a variable that keeps track of if you ended up in a point you want to exit from and check it at the beginning of your inner loop running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marcel said in his comment, the easiest thing to do would be to put the inner while loop in its own function and return early from it.

```py
def calc_sub_loop():
    # your calculator here

    elif sub_inp == 'Go Back':
        go_to_sub_loop()
        return

        # Internal While loop
        internal_loop = inputYesNo(f'\nDo you want to conduct {sub_inp} again ? [Yes/No]:  ')
    if internal_loop == 'yes':
        print()
        sub_loop()
    else:
        return
```

You can just write another sub loop function like this for your unit converter.
I also am going to put getting `main_inp` in separate function as well.

```py
def go_to_sub_loop():
    # take main_inp
    if main_inp == "calc":
        calc_sub_loop()
    elif main_inp == "unit":
        unit_sub_loop()
```

The main while loop might look something like this.

```py
choice_loop = 'yes'
while choice_loop == 'yes':

    go_to_sub_loop()

    choice_loop = inputYesNo('\nDo you want to access another Category ? [Yes/No]: ')
    if choice_loop == 'yes':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

This should work. This code is however untested so if you have any problems please let me know and I'll be happy to help you.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you so very much ! I learnt a new thing because of you, return without anything in front of it works like break in loops... I've messaged you something in reddit check it out !